# Gaussian oscillatory integral evaluation using regularization

Tags: path-integral, integration, regularization

To evaluate the Gaussian integral

$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx e^{iax^2} = \sqrt{\frac{\pi i}{a}}, 
$$

one can use an appropriate contour as [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/368186/), or use the method of "regularization", contained for example in [Ashok](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/9812568476) p24, Eq. (2.39):

$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx e^{\frac{im}{2\hbar \epsilon}x^2} = \operatorname{lim_{\delta\rightarrow 0^+}}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx e^{(\frac{im}{2\hbar \epsilon}-\delta)x^2} = \sqrt{\frac{2\pi i\hbar\epsilon}{m}}.\tag{2.39}
$$

Once one introduces this new parameter $\delta$, how the integration is carried out? Is it that I have to perform the integral over the complex plane as in the first case?

Comment: The Feynman $i\delta$-regularization in eq. (2.39) is essentially what is done in part II of my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/391364/2451).

Comment: I saw it. I hope someone can give a clearer answer along the same lines.