# Can $\int e^{ix^2 t} dx$ be defined without going to imaginary time?

Tags: integration, complex-numbers, regularization

The motivation is trying to define the path integral, where at some point we get the integral
$$
Z=\int e^{iS}Dx
$$
which is then taken to imaginary time
$$
Z_E=\int e^{-S_E}Dx
$$
such that $Z_E$ can be calculated and then analytically continued back to real-time.

---

The bare bones of what I am wondering is if we have the integral
$$
I=\int e^{ix^2 t}dx
$$
can this be understood or evaluated without taking $t\mapsto -i\tau$ (or equivalently $x\mapsto z-i\epsilon$)

Comment: The function $e^{ix^2 t}$ is not absolute integrable, and it needs some kind "regularization". Changing from a real $t$ to a complex variable makes the integral convergent inside the half plane and the real variable integral then can be interpreted as being a limit to a generalized "function".

Comment: See [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/390910/2451) Phys.SE answer by Jack.