# Gaussian wave packet with complex coefficients

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, momentum, fourier-transform, complex-numbers

I am trying to obtain a representation of the momentum-space wavefunction $<p'|\alpha>$

Its position space wavefunction is given as
$$ <x'|\alpha> = N \exp [-(a+ib)x'^2 +(c+id)x'] $$
where $N,a,b,c,d$ are all real.

I have tried to calculate the following integral using Gaussian integral, or Fourier transform method but both were not easy because of the complex numbers in the exponent.

$$ <p'|\alpha> = \int dx' <p'|x'><x'|\alpha> = \int dx' {1 \over \sqrt{(2 \pi \hbar)}} 
 \exp[-i{p'x' \over \hbar}] N \text{exp} [-(a+ib)x'^2 +(c+id)x'] dx'$$

where I have used $$<p'|x'> = {1 \over \sqrt{(2 \pi \hbar)}}  \exp[-i{p'x' \over \hbar}].$$

Can someone give me a hint about calculating indefinite integral with complex exponent?

Comment: Hint 1: Try completing the square in the exponential. Does the resulting function seem familiar? Hint 2: It is just a Gaussian integral https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral !

Comment: Some of the formulas for gaussian integration continue to work regardless of whether the parameters are real or complex, and regardless of whether you are integrating along the real line ($-\infty$ to $\infty$), or along a line in the real direction but displaced off the real axis ($-\infty + i\Delta$ to $+\infty + i\Delta$). This means you can often play fast and loose with your variable substitutions and your limits of integration and still get the right answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gaussian integral with imaginary coefficients and Wick rotation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/368186/gaussian-integral-with-imaginary-coefficients-and-wick-rotation)

Comment: Or this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1297096/gaussian-integral-with-a-shift-in-the-complex-plane

Answer (score 2):

Given your integral:

$$
\langle p'|\alpha\rangle = \int dx' \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \hbar}} \exp\left(-\frac{i p'x'}{\hbar}\right) N \exp\left[-(a+ib)x'^2 +(c+id)x'\right]
$$

You can complete the square within the exponent term involving $x'$:
$$
-(a+ib)x'^2 +(c+id)x' = -a(x' - \frac{c+id}{2a})^2 + \left(\frac{(c+id)^2}{4a} - ib\right)
$$

Then, you have:
$$
\langle p'|\alpha\rangle = N\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \hbar}} \exp\left(\frac{(c+id)^2}{4a} - ib\right) \int dx' \exp\left[-a\left(x' - \frac{c+id}{2a}\right)^2\right] \exp\left(-\frac{i p'x'}{\hbar}\right)
$$

Now the integral looks more tractable as it's a [Gaussian integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral) and you can use the standard results for Gaussian integrals to evaluate it.