# How do I show that Thermal Field Theory works?

Tags: thermodynamics, quantum-field-theory, field-theory, wick-rotation

Of course it does work. What I'm asking is:
**What is the easiest-to-understand, most direct example that shows that [Thermal Field Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_quantum_field_theory) is a predictive theory that actually describes how temperature affects reality?**

Anyone who has taken a couple of courses in modern QFT has encountered the idea that if you take the time variable $t$ in your partition function and make it complex ($\tau=it$) and compact ($0\le\tau\le\beta$), then you're describing a theory with temperature $T=1/\beta$. I know where this idea comes from, that the exponential of the partition function is $-\beta H$ and the one of the (left) evolution operator is $-itH$, and now that I've used all of this for some time it makes natural sense to me. But when I tried to explain this to a mathematician friend of mine he pointed out that it's kind of a big leap. I wanted to reply "It is, but it works!" but I couldn't find an example to prove my point.

Comment: I mean the Boltzmann distribution in general has, around 150 years of evidence supporting it at this point. For thermal field theory specifically, it is really a framework for more specific theories to be built. So Fermi liquid theory, BCS theory and generally a large chunk of "standard" condensed matter physics at finite temperature can be coached in terms of thermal field theory

Comment: Kind of related/duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/110360

Comment: Do you mean not only partition-function-related applications, but something more? For instance, computation of smth in QFT and then perform Wick rotation in order to make a prediction for stat-mech system, isn't it?

Comment: @ArtemAlexandrov exactly! I mean something analogous to the fact that renormalization accounts for the anomalous magnetic moment of the electron. Some might say it's a weird idea to work with infinities and subtract counterterms, but the Physics™ says it works!

Comment: @MauroGiliberti , OK, what about linear response theory, Kubo formula and so on? The crucial moment in these concepts is rotation from Matsubara frequencies to real one

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is more logic connecting thermal field theory and quantum field theory than what you wrote. In particular, there is a [*Wick rotation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wick_rotation) that relates the path integral integrand $\sim e^{i S/\hbar}$ (where $S$ is the action) to $\sim e^{- \beta H}$. Then, if you started from the definition of the partition function in statistical mechanics, you would get a sum over states with a weight $\sim e^{- \beta H}$. So there is a legitimate (at least at a physics-level-of-rigor) mathematical step that relates the natural definition of a QFT partition function to the natural definition of a statistical mechanics partition function. It's more than noticing a formal similarity between two formulas.

Second, if you are looking for an example where a path integral is useful in statistical mechanics, some classic examples are [Landau-Ginzburg theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ginzburg%E2%80%93Landau_theory) and effective field theory, for example applied to the [Ising model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ising_model#4_%E2%88%92_%CE%B5_dimensions_%E2%80%93_renormalization_group).

However, using a path integral is kind of a technical detail, that has more to do with the state space than the fundamental underlying Boltzmann distribution $\sim e^{-\beta H}$ that underlies statistical mechanics. The Boltzmann distribution is used in many contexts, maybe the simplest is the [ideal gas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_gas) which is used to derive bounds on the [efficiency of heat engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_efficiency), among other things. Quantum mechanically, the Boltzmann distribution also underlies the [Fermi-Dirac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi%E2%80%93Dirac_statistics) and [Bose-Einstein distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bose%E2%80%93Einstein_statistics), which (among other things) are used to describe semi-conductor physics and the Planck spectrum of radiation, respectively.