# Does anybody know of a source that explains Wick rotation for fermions in 3-dimensional spacetime?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, fermions, spinors, wick-rotation

I've been looking for a long time and I've not had a lot of luck. I've found sources that **use** fermions in 3d Euclidean space but I can't find any that explain the Wick rotation from Minkowski space.

This [source](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9608174) provides a nice explanation of the Wick rotation procedure for fermions in 4d. However it leaves the odd dimensional case as an open question.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/21261/2451

Comment: Perhaps one method would be to perform the Wick rotation in 4d and then compactify a spatial direction to a get an (effective) 3d result. One might be able to generalise to higher odd dimensions by compactifying 6d, 8d, etc... in a similar manner.