# Analytic cotinuation between Minkowskian and Euclidean space, and causality

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, causality, unitarity, wick-rotation

We can flip between Minkowkian and Euclidean signature by Wick rotation, and it is a well defined operation, provided there are no non - trivial singularities.

Now, Unitarity in Minkowskian space corresponds to reflection positivity in the Euclidean signature.
Does Causality in the Mikowskian space has a well defined and "useful" continuation to the Euclidean signature?

Comment: In what theory? [Related question for fermions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/21261/2451).

Comment: Continuum limit of 2D Ising model

Comment: Any theory you can think of?