# How does the $+i\varepsilon$ prescription in the propagator comes from analytic continuation of the Euclidean 2-point function?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, propagator, wick-rotation, analyticity

Let $S_0[\phi]$ be the action for a real Klein-Gordon field $$S_0[\phi]=\dfrac{1}{2}\int d^Dx \phi(x)(\Box-m^2)\phi(x)\tag{1}.$$

If we try to construct the generating functional $Z_0[j]$ we find that we must invert the operator ${\cal D}=\Box-m^2$. In other words we must find $\Delta(x-y)$ which obeys $$(\Box-m^2)\Delta(x)=\delta(x)\Longrightarrow -(k^2+m^2)\hat{\Delta}(k)=1\tag{2},$$
where we transformed the equation to Fourier space. Now since we are in Lorentzian signature we can have $k^2\leq 0$. Indeed it is possible that $k^2=-m^2$. This makes it ambiguous on how to define $\Delta(x)$ since we will eventually integrate over all $k$ and there will be values of $k$ on which the denominator of the integrand vanishes. This is of course solved with the $i\varepsilon$ prescription.

Now, consider instead $S_0^E[\phi]$ the Euclidean action in Euclidean singature. If we follow the same steps now ${\cal D}$ is replaced with ${\cal D}^E=\nabla^2-m^2$. The thing is that now this operator has no ambiguity in its inverse. The point is that if we repeat equation (2) now since the signature is Euclidean $k^2>0$. We have $$\hat{\Delta}_E(k)=-\dfrac{1}{k^2+m^2}\tag{3}\Longrightarrow \Delta_E(x-y)=-\int\dfrac{d^D k}{(2\pi)^D}\dfrac{e^{ik(x-y)}}{k^2+m^2}$$
and there is no ambiguity because the integrand is well-defined in the whole integration region.

My question here is this: suppose we start with the Euclidean two-point function $\Delta_E(x-y)$ and use analytic continuation to define the Lorentzian $\Delta(x-y)$. How does analytic continuation produce the $+i\varepsilon$ prescription? Moreover, how can one, starting from the Euclidean version, arrive at different prescriptions for the inverse of (2), like for instance $-i\varepsilon$?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/457591/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/455387/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 2):

Viewed as a complex function of the Euclidean time $\tau$, the propagator has a branch cut. It is therefore ambiguous how one continues $\tau$ to the imaginary axis. Which sign of $i\epsilon$ you use controls which side of the branch cut you move along. Physically, this is the choice of how the fields are ordered in Minkowski signature.

The nicest discussion of this I've seen is in https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.00014.

Comment: According to the reference you gave, there are branch cuts/points on interacting theories, but as far as I understand there are no such things in free theories. In this case, how can one choose different ordering conventions?