# Feynman $i\epsilon$-prescription for fermion propagator via path integrals

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, fermions, regularization

In Section 9.4 of S. Weinberg's book "The quantum theory of fields" it is shown how to get the Feynman $i\epsilon$-prescription in the propagator of a free scalar field using path integrals and explicit construction of the vacuum vector in the space of functionals on field (for the vacuum see formulas (9.2.9) and (9.2.12)).

> It is claimed that there is a version of these constructions for fermions which leads to analogous Feynman $i\epsilon$-prescription in the propagator. The details are not presented. I am wondering about them. In particular I will be happy to see an analogous explicit description of the vacuum vector.

Since in the case of fermions one should use Berezin integration, there might be some subtleties.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/21261/2451